# Catching global exception and prevent app crash

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app that makes request to server and gets response. I am using `Retrofit2` and `OkHttp`.
I get response in `JSOn` which is then parsed using `GSON`. Sometimes , the object might be null and the app crashes. I have response coming in several fragments so the app might crash in any part if response has some null object.

So I planned to have global exception catching class that catches exception and does not crash the app but show some custom dialog to the user saying `"Call Support"`.

I do not want to have that Android dialog `"App not responding"`.
How can I achieve this? My app must not crash in any case even though the server send sme null object.

Comment: the app will not crash even though server sends null object. Retrofit will takes care of it. Might be check with your POJO class.

Comment: "Sometimes , the object might be null and the app crashes" -- validate the response from the server and gracefully handle invalid data, rather than blindly passing the data along and crashing. "I have response coming in several fragments so the app might crash in any part if response has some null object" -- centralize your code for getting data from the server, and validate the response. "My app must not crash in any case even though the server send sme null object" -- then validate the response from the server. A global exception handler is not an appropriate solution here, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of making the application crash when an exception is uncaught, is stopping the execution from executing unexpected behaviour (which is often the lesser evil).

Having an uncaught exception in your code means that a method was asked to do something that made no sense (hence throwing an exception) and that your code never expected/designed any way to recover from that state. Crashing the application is the best behavior possible.

If you (as the developer) expect the server to sometimes send null object, then you should handle null objects as soon as that makes sense.

On a bigger picture side, if you expect your messaging module to potentially fail and still design a meaningful behavior for your application from that situation, you should then wrap the entirer module with a sensible ExceptionHandler.